# How to replace a specific occurrence of a substring within a file, using Bash?

Tags: bash

For example, "abc" shows up 10 times in a file.

I'm looping through each line using a Bash script and because of how "abc" is scoped in the file (it comes after a certain combination of '{' and '}'), I only want to replace two of the occurrences with "xyz".

I am able to identify these two occurrences and print their line number; how do I then replace them with "xyz"?

Comment: Please post a sample input and desired output. Also what have  you tried?

Comment: I'd usually lean towards `awk` for this kind of job, but the question is too vague to allow a specific answer as currently written. (BTW, if your input is JSON, then that calls for a completely different answer, one using format-aware tools such as `jq`).